# aligning a struct member in C to 32 bytes,

Tags: c, arrays, memory-alignment

I have the following code extract in C,

```
typedef struct Item{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  double d;
  double e;
  double* f;
  double* g;
} Item;
```

I have an array of this struct item declared as,

```
  Item* result[/*no.of threads*/];
```

When I initialise this struct, I want it to align it to 32 bytes so I did the following within a for loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
      posix_memalign((void **)&result[i], 32, sizeof(Item));
}
```

but this gives me the following error,

```
 error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
```

am I not allowed to do this operation? if so, are there any other method of aligning the array to a specific size?

Compiler: clang 3.4 on x86

Comment: Array is tightly packed, you cannot realign single array element. You only need to align first element when allocating array, and probably mark structure with e.g. `__attribute__ ((aligned (32)))` for gcc.

Comment: @keltar: array is an array of pointers. The OP is allocating separate structures for each thread. He wants those structures aligned on 32 bytes and is using `posix_memalign` to allocate them.

Comment: @chqrlie yeah was disturbed by nonsense error message so haven't looked at code closely. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message does not pertain to the code posted, you probably miss the definition of `i` in your original code.

Methods to align the structure on 32 byte boundaries are non portable.  You a allocating each structure with a system specific API that is supposed to do the job, but the compiler does not know that.  You have to tell the compiler about the alignment constraint on the `struct` itself with a special compiler specific attribute. Furthermore, if you want each structure to be aligned on 32 bytes to use AVX extensions to store results in to it, you need to reorder the members so the `double`s are at the beginning, thus properly aligned.

C11 introduced a portable alternative to `posix_memalign`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

You can use that if your system supports it, but be aware that `size` must be a multiple of `alignment`, so you may need to write:

```
aligned_alloc(32, (sizeof(Item) + 31) / 32 * 32);
```